# How to creat object of self created constructor

Tags: java, list, jsp, object, constructor

**i want to use my created objects**

1. i retrieve data from MySQL and put it into Linked List of my class type
2. i created my class, declare objects and create constructor also
3. now i want to get value from that variables

Here the code i am trying

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM request";
    try (
        Statement st = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);)
    {
        while (rs.next())
        {
            /*String f_name = rs.getString("f_name");
            String l_name = rs.getString("l_name");
            String email = rs.getString("email");
            String contact = rs.getString("contact");
            result += (f_name+",.,"+l_name+",.,"+email+",.,"+contact); */
            List<Request> get_request= new ArrayList<Request>();
            get_request.add(new Request(rs));
        }
    }
```

**class where i am trying to store**

```
package com.Utility.umair;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
public class Request {
String f_name;
String l_name;
String email;
String contact;
String Organization;
public Request(ResultSet rs)
    {
        try
        {
            f_name = rs.getString("f_name");
            l_name = rs.getString("l_name");
            email = rs.getString("email");
            contact = rs.getString("contact");
            Organization = rs.getString("organization");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Where i want to retrieve my data**

```
<%@page import="com.Utility.umair.Request"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" 
    import = "com.request_handling.umair.DbLayer.RequestHandlingDb" 
    import = "java.io.IOException"
    import = "java.sql.SQLException" %>
   <%
   List<Request> string  = RequestHandlingDb.ViewRole();
   System.out.println(string);
   %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

i don't know how i can get data now in jsp or my i doing in wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it all wrong.

1. You cannot have an object added to a null object.

   List get_request=null;
                       get_request.add(new Request(rs));
2. Creating a new object. A new object will never give you any value till you do not assign it.

   Request re = new Request();
      System.out.println(re.f_name);

Ideally it should have been

```
public class Whatever{

public static List<Request> getResults(){
String query = "SELECT * FROM request";
List<Request> get_request= new ArrtList<Request>;
        try {
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next())
            {
                /*String f_name = rs.getString("f_name");
                String l_name = rs.getString("l_name");
                String email = rs.getString("email");
                String contact = rs.getString("contact");
                result += (f_name+",.,"+l_name+",.,"+email+",.,"+contact); */

                get_request.add(new Request(rs));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        return get_request;

}
```

In your jsp get it as follows

```
Whatever.getResults()
```